# How do I make this code not encrypt messages if it finds a special character or number inputted?

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to make this code print a message if it finds the user types a special character and/or number and exits the code instead of just printing out the special character and/or number again.

I'm quite new to here, any help would be appreciated. My code is below:

```py
#!/bin/python3

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
special = '[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]1234567890'
newMessage = ''

message = input('Please enter a message to encyrpt: ').lower()

key = input('Please enter a key from 1-26: ')
key = int(key)

for character in message:
  if character in alphabet:
    position = alphabet.find(character)
    newPosition = (position + key) % 26
    newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
    #print('The new character is is:', newCharacter)
    newMessage += newCharacter
  else:
    newMessage += character

print('Your new encrypted message is:', newMessage)
```

Comment: You can `break` out of a for-loop. You can use the else-part of a for-loop or a flag variable to distinguish if the encoding completed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below example:

- Checks each character of the string `message` given by the user at runtime and passes it into a list `specialInMessage = [c for c in special if c in message]`
- Checks the list (`if specialInMessage:`), printing a message to the console and exiting the execution of any further code using the builtin `sys` module (`sys.exit()`) if there are any characters that made it through the above list comprehension into `specialInMessage`
- If the above conditional (`if specialInMessage`) does not pass - i.e. there are no values from `special` present in `message` - the code will not execute the block exiting the program and continue to ask for a key value, encrypt message etc.

```py
import sys # Import builtin sys module 

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
special = '[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]1234567890'
newMessage = ''

message = input('Please enter a message to encyrpt: ').lower()

specialInMessage = [c for c in special if c in message] # Make a list of characters from special that are present in message
if specialInMessage: # If new list has any characters in it
    print('Invalid character found in message, exiting program') # Message to console
    sys.exit() # End execution of code
        
key = input('Please enter a key from 1-26: ')
key = int(key)

for character in message:
  if character in alphabet:
    position = alphabet.find(character)
    newPosition = (position + key) % 26
    newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
    newMessage += newCharacter
  else:
    newMessage += character

print(f'Your new encrypted message is: {newMessage}')
```

If you want to tell the user specifically which character(s) from their input are invalid these can be accessed directly from the `specialInMessage` list - probably best from within the `if specialInMessage` block to ensure that list index access is only attempted when there are actually invalid characters at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Although, went it prints, it prints: ('Your new encrypted message is: ', newMessage) Instead of: Your new encrypted message is: newMessage

Comment: Glad it works for you. Sorry about the mistake there - probably an error somewhere on my part in pasting the code in from writing it in notepad :S. I've updated the final line now, tested and should print out your message followed by the ciphertext generated.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Although, I still get that issue.

Comment: Actually, I've fixed this. I had to do: print('Your new encrypted message is: ' + newMessage) Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `break`

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
special = '[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]1234567890'
newMessage = ''

message = input('Please enter a message to encyrpt: ').lower()

key = input('Please enter a key from 1-26: ')
key = int(key)

for character in message:
  if character in alphabet:
    position = alphabet.find(character)
    newPosition = (position + key) % 26
    newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
    #print('The new character is is:', newCharacter)
    newMessage += newCharacter
  elif character in special:
      newMessage = 'encrypting Error'
      break
  else:
    newMessage += character

print('Your new encrypted message is:', newMessage)
```

Comment: Hey this is helpful, but I was more looking for the answer I accepted.